Why are zero-modes preserved on turning on coupling in twisted bilayer graphene model?
In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05250 on page 3, they talk about how when the parameter $\alpha$ in the Hamiltonian in Eq. (5) equals $0$, we get zero modes at the Dirac points K and K’. This seems to follow from the dispersion relation near the Dirac points in the two uncoupled layers.
However, I did not understand their argument for why the zero-modes are preserved at non-zero $\alpha$ when the two layers are coupled. Is it because the Dirac points don’t change as you turn on $\alpha$?
